# Submit new build when I'm in "Pending Developer Release" in AppStore

Tags: app-store

I searched a lot on StackOverflow and Googled a lot but I didn't find the exact answer I was looking for.

I recently submitted my application to the App Store review after several weeks of testing with TestFlight.
My application has been accepted on the App Store, and I indicated that I would like to do a manual release. So my application currently has the status "Pending Developer Release".

My build 1 is now ready to be released on the App Store.
The launch of my app is in a few weeks and I would like to have my build 2 (which already contains bug fixes) validated by the AppStore before the launch of my application. However, if my build 2 doesn't pass the App Store review before the launch of my app, I would like to be able to launch my build 1 anyway.

On the AppStore, I can't upload a new build if my old one hasn't been released. I have to cancel the already released build.

So I was wondering how to do this.
Can I, for example, validate my build 1 on the AppStore and set the availability to "no country"? and the day I launch, I just change the availability to "all countries"?

I hope I made myself clear!

Thanks, 
Viktor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first , if you have a build with state **Pending Developer Release** for version (ex: 1.0.0)
you cannot upload a new build with same version (ie 1.0.0)

Or Else if you want to upload a new build with same version 1.0.0 you should cancel already approved build for version (ie 1.0.0) which changes the state of the build to **Developer Rejected** , in this state you can upload new build ( with probable bug fixes ) on same version (1.0.0)

If for some reason apple rejects your new build ( They inform why they rejected though), you cannot go back to already approved build.

Now if you want to release the build and make it **Ready for Sale** state then it's visibility in Appstore depends on Availability in Countries.

If you make Availability  to none , then the build state for version 1.0.0 changes to **Developer Removed From Sale** ( No need to panic , if you add one or more countries in Availability the state would change to **Ready for Sale** state again)

However this makes you restricted from using 1.0.0 version again , so you need to use 1.0.1 or any new version greater than previous one.

If versioning is not an issue , you can release 1.0.0 and remove countries , so even if newer build (1.0.1) is rejected by apple , you can still release your app on the pre-decided date.

Hope this is helpful information.

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer! Couldn't get any better! I was going to try, but I was wondering about the ASO if I put the countries to none!

But now I'm going to do that! Thank you again so much! It's really a precious help!

Comment: @ViktorJovanovic Glad it helped :)

Comment: I am not able to upload the build with the same version even if I cancelled the release and status was Developer rejected. It's asking me to upload build with incremented version.